# Computing Cosine Distance with Differently shaped tensors

Tags: pytorch, cosine-similarity

I have the following tensor  representing a word vector

```
A = (2, 500)
```

Where the first dimension is the BATCH dimension (i.e. A contains two word vectors each with 500 elements)

I also have the following tensor

```
B = (10, 500)
```

I want to compute the cosine distance between A and B such that I get

```
C = (2, 10, 1)
```

i.e for each row in A compute the cosine distance with each row in B

I looked at using `torch.nn.functional.F.cosine_similarity` however this doesn't work as  the dimensions must be the same.

Whats the best efficient way of achieving this in pytorch?

Comment: Minor typo/lingo in what you typed: it's `torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) technique with `unsqueeze`

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

C = F.cosine_similarity(A.unsqueeze(1), B, dim=-1)

print(C.shape)
# torch.size([2,10])
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted solution appears to be inefficient --it took forever on my machine and finally crushed the kernel due to insufficient memory-- while this solution took a few milliseconds:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

# cosine similarity = normalize the vectors & multiply
C = F.normalize(A) @ F.normalize(B).t()
```

This is the implementation in [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/util.py#L23)